# Can the solution of this system of equations be found?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

With known variables $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, how can I find $(\theta, \psi, \varphi) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with the following system?

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a &= cos(\theta) \\
2b &= sin(\psi-\theta)-sin(\psi+\theta) \\
2c &= sin(\varphi+\theta)-sin(\varphi-\theta)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

I've never learned to solve something like that. Also, the system solvers that I found on the Internet take too much time to compute the solution and give up.

Comment: $\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b)=2\cos a\sin b$.

Comment: Expand out $\sin(\psi - \theta) - \sin (\psi + \theta)$  It becomes a more simple expression.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Don Thousand and Doug M. Here is the solution:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a &= cos(\theta) \\
2b &= sin(\psi-\theta)-sin(\psi+\theta) \\
2c &= sin(\varphi+\theta)-sin(\varphi-\theta)
\end{aligned}
\right. \\[2ex]
\Leftrightarrow\;&\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\theta &= cos^{-1}(a) \\
b &= -cos(\psi)sin(\theta) \\
c &= cos(\varphi)sin(\theta)
\end{aligned}
\right. \\[2ex]
\Leftrightarrow\;&\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\theta &= cos^{-1}(a) \\
\psi &= cos^{-1}\biggl(-\frac{b}{sin(cos^{-1}(a))}\biggr) \\
\varphi &= cos^{-1}\biggl(\frac{c}{sin(cos^{-1}(a))}\biggr)
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: just remember that $a = \cos(\theta)$ has many solutions: $\theta = \pm \cos^{-1}(a)+2\pi n$